# How can I retrieve values from a DropDownList dynamically added to a GridView in the RowUpdating event?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm very new to ASP.NET and really programming in general. I have a GridView to which I've added a DropDownList on edit in the RowDataBound event. The existing control is readonly and does not seem to display on edit.

```
protected void GridViewVehicles_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
     {
         if (e.Row.RowState == DataControlRowState.Edit) 
         {
             DropDownList ddlVehicles = GetVehicles();
             string make = e.Row.Cells[9].Text;
             ddlVehicles.Items.FindByText(reportsTo).Selected = true;
             e.Row.Cells[10].Controls.Add(ddlVehicles);
         }
     }
}
```

The problem is that I cannot seem to access the selected value of the DropDownList in the RowUpdating event. That table cell seems to have a controls count of 0. The following throws and Argument Out of Range exception.

```
protected void GridViewEmployees_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    string vehicle = ((DropDownList)(row.Cells[10].Controls[0])).SelectedValue;
}
```

In the Chrome debugger, I do see the correct value being posted, but I just can't figure out how to access it.

I've read that it might be possible to use the OnSelectedIndexChanged event for the DropDownList and store the value in ViewState, but I've been having difficulty with that as well.

Any guidance on how best to proceed would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It looks like I can access the value by using Request.Forms.GetValues(), which I found here: http://www.aspsnippets.com/articles/creating-dynamic-dropdownlist-controls-in-asp.net.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the method `GetVehicles()` is dynamically creating the drop-down list, since you are adding the drop-down to Controls collection on the last line of second if statement.

When you are dynamically creating controls, you have to recreate them on every postback.

Instead, place the drop-down control inside `EditItemTemplate` and then find this control using the `FindControl` method and populate it in code behind like you are doing now.

Here is the example of GridView definition:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="GridViewVehicles" OnRowDataBound="GridViewVehicles_RowDataBound" OnRowUpdating="GridViewVehicles_RowUpdating">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <!-- Text of selected drop-down item -->    
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlVehicles" />
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

And the code-behind:

```
protected void GridViewVehicles_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow && e.Row.RowState == DataControlRowState.Edit)
            {
                //Get the drop-down datasource and perform databinding
            }
        }

        protected void GridViewVehicles_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
        {
            DropDownList ddlVehicles = GridViewVehicles.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("ddlVehicles") as DropDownList;

            if (ddlVehicles != null)
            {
                string selectedValue = ddlVehicles.SelectedValue;
            }
        }
```

Hope it helps!

Regards,

Uroš

Comment: Thanks! I think this does it.